# Is my proof correct for scaling of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Prove $$\lim_{x \to a} cf(x) = c\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$$

Let $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, where

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_1 > 0 : (0 < |x-a| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{|c| + 1})$$

We wish to show that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 : (0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |cf(x) - cL| < \epsilon)$$

If we set $\delta = \delta_1$ then

$$|cf(x) - cL| = |c||f(x) - L| < (|c| + 1)|f(x) - L| < (|c| + 1) \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{|c| + 1} = \epsilon$$

Is this proof correct? Should it work for any real $c$? I had to modify this a little to get it so the denominators wouldn't be $c=0$.

Comment: I think there's no problem at all!

Comment: If $c=0$ it is a trivial case, you could consider it separately. And for $c \neq 0$ you wouldn't have to deal with $|c| + 1$ in the denominator. However, your proof is correct

Comment: If $c = -1$, then $|c+1| = 0$, which is not greater than $|c|$.

Comment: @AOrtiz Edited, that should fix it I think, right? Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @user537069 It's all good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems okay after the edit. I propose a structure to an alternate proof:

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}, \ f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two functions for which the limit exists. After proving the Algebraic Limit Theorem on  Multiplication for Function Limits, $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} \left(f\cdot g\right)(x) = \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) \cdot \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$$ one can define a constant function $g(x) = c, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Trivially then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = c$ and hence the result follows. The result is a corollary of an even more general statement. Needless to say, a direct proof is also correct!